# JetBrains IDEs: How to add semicolon automatically?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, ide, jetbrains-ide, automatic-semicolon-insertion

Is there a way to add semicolons automatically when inserting a function in JetBrains IDEs? such as Android Studio and IntelliJ IDEA etc.

[image: the suggestion]
*(in the example here I am using Flutter in Android Studio)*

When I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> it adds the function, but the semicolon is missing. I know that it's not a big deal nor a problem but why not?! Maybe someone has the answer.

[image: after inserting the suggestion, it comes without a semicolon]

Answer (score 4):

You can try using `Ctrl-Shift-Enter` (Windows/Linux) or `Command-Shift-Enter` (macOS).

Feel free to upvote on the related request in JetBrains issues tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-260065

Comment: Hi, thank you. Could you please indicate what is the keymap name of Command+Shift+Enter so I can change it on setting to a more convenient key? I will also upvote the feature request, semicolons in Java are a little bit annoying to me.